# Mono.Security load problem

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, ldap

I have tried connecting to a LDAP server using novell SDK but it doesnt seems to work because of Mono issue. Can any one suggest me any other method to work with LDAP via SSL in C#?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: 'Mono issue'? Please explain.

Comment: it gives an exception when tries to connect to the server saying that Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Security, Version=1.0.5000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0738eb9f132ed756' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). I downloaded different versions of mono.security.dll  but the problem remained unsolved, as this is for a urgent project i try hunt down other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the Mono.Security.dll file that comes with the Novell.Directory.Ldap.dll you downloaded, otherwise you'll run into binary compatibility issue.

Note that the version number of Mono.Security.dll match the framework version since this assembly is part of the Mono framework where it is used by most of its security tools. As such you cannot go around and look for the file (well you could be lucky, but don't count on it) you need the one that was used to test Novell.Directory.Ldap.dll.